# AG-Grid how do you apply or keep the pagination state after refreshServerSide?

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

I am using VueJS, ag-grid (v. 24)

How do I keep the state of my grid (filters, pagination) when I perform refreshServerSide?
https://www.ag-grid.com/vue-data-grid/server-side-model-updating-refresh/

My grid uses server side data.